# Edit uploaded file client side with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web application where the user have to upload a file.
Before sending it to server, I will need to modify that file on client side.

Here is the code for loading the file :

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(file) {
    var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    //modify byteArray
    //replace the file data with the modified byteArray
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Is it possible to replace the file data with the modified byteArray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) object, as that represents a file on the user's local filesystem. However, you can create a new [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) from your modified array buffer:

```
var uploadBlob = new Blob(arrayBuffer);
```

Then simply upload this uploadBlob in place of the original File object using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```
var uploadData = new FormData(),
    request = null;

upload.append('fileData', uploadBlob);

request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://yourURL.com");
request.send(formData);
```

(Obviously, remember to add any needed handlers to deal with your request's response.)

The only issue is browser support (basically, IE10+):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

http://caniuse.com/#feat=blobbuilder