# CSV-File on localhost: How to edit a csv-file dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, edit

I made an HTML5-File for a school assignment. This file runs on local host. A button click on the page triggers the download of an empty csv file, that is going to be populated with time. I use the following code to do that and it works just fine.

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:csv/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

    document.getElementById("Data_id").addEventListener("click", function(){download("mouse_data", "");}, false);
```

What I would like to do is, dynamically add new elements to this file. I've had a look at [How to update csv file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018390/how-to-update-csv-file-using-javascript) and [Edit uploaded file client side with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177274/edit-uploaded-file-client-side-with-javascript).I feel like these don't answer my queston. But I'm a newbie and don't really know how to program with javascript and html. Maybe I am missing something? Hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think it'll work to populate the file after it's downloaded. Share more about what problem you're working on? We might be able to point you at an easier way to solve it.

Comment: @NathanWalther, I am tracking the user's -in this case that's me- mouse data. I would ideally edit this downloaded file every time the user has moved the mouse, or clicked, dragged etc. until he clicked on the save or the cancel button or closed the tab.

Comment: A more typical way to implement this is for the browser to send mouse data to a server-side app such as Node, which then persists the data (appending to a file would work fine for a school assignment). You'll have much better filesystem access server side than client side, and you can still keep things simple by running Node on localhost.