# POST request to a local JSON from React

Tags: json, reactjs

im trying to understand React and POST request, is it possible to modify a local JSON file from react, a file essentially stored on a hard disk? there are a lot of articles online about getting information from a local json and displaying it onto view components, but not a lot of documentation about modifying a local json, which leads me to ask the question if it is even possible to do so?
if not, what other alternatives do i have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177274/edit-uploaded-file-client-side-with-javascript

Comment: no im sorry i dont understand it too well :/ Simply put what im trying to do is modify a json file in the project directory through react, but although there are a lot of resources online on how to read a json, there arent too many on how to modify one, i was wondering if i were to modify a local json, how do i go about doing so?

Comment: You can't modify and save a file using a client-side script(React in your case), you have to use some server-side scripting like NodeJS to do that. However, if you just want to modify something in the JSON file and then maybe send it to the server, then you can first read the JSON file, make a copy and then modify the copy(just like a JavaScipt object) and then send that modified copy to the server.

Comment: If you really have to store something after you modify it on the client-side, use localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

No. POST requires a server that reads the request and acts on it. No operating system acts as a web server and just overrides the file with the content of the response.

Operating systems only support the `file://` protocol like a normal double click on a file that doesn't require a server. So, no other verbs are supported.